# How to place a canvas object at the bottom of the window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

So I want to place a rectangle at the bottom of my window. How do I find the right y-coordinate? My window is turned on fullscreen, so the y-coordinate isn't always the same.

Since I don't know much about the math python uses and I sometimes find for me weird solutions for my problems, I've tried using integers. Of course I googled my problem, but couldn't find a working solution.

```py
from tkinter import *
def run(): #I define it, so I can import it and use it in other files.
    w=Tk()
    w.state('zoomed')
    w.title('A title')
    bg=Canvas(w,bg='#808080',borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0)
    bg.pack(fill='both',expand=True)

    ywindow=w.winfo_screenheight()
    yfooter=ywindow-30
    footer=Canvas(w,bg='#A5A5A5',borderwidth=2,highlightthickness=0)
    footer.place(height=30,width=w.winfo_screenwidth(),x=0,y=yfooter)

run()
```

I expect tkinter using the coordinate 30 pixels away from the border as y, but it doesn't show the `Canvas` at all.

Comment: If you want it at the bottom, and are otherwise using `.pack()` in the same container, then simply use `.pack(side=BOTTOM)`.

Comment: Are you asking about placing the rectangle, or asking about placing the cnavas? If you are asking about the canvas, read the documentation on `place`. You can specify coordinates relative to an edge.

Answer (score 0):

While I not sure I understand your goals, but suggesting to someone that they read the tkinter [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), as @Bryan Oakley did in a comment, is kind of a cruel joke IMO, the module's docs are so bad...

Anyway, here's a guess that shows how to do what I think you may want:

```
from tkinter import *

def run():
    win = Tk()
    win.state('zoomed')
    win.title('A title')

    FH = 30  # Footer height
    header_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
    footer_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()

    footer_height = FH
    header_height = win.winfo_screenheight() - FH

    split = header_height / win.winfo_screenheight() # How much header occupies.

    header = Canvas(win, bg='#808080', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                    width=header_width, height=header_height)
    header.place(rely=0, relheight=split, relwidth=1, anchor=N,
                 width=header_width, height=header_height)

    footer = Canvas(win, bg='#A5A5A5', borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=0,
                    width=footer_width, height=footer_height)

    footer.place(rely=split, relheight=1.0-split, relwidth=1, anchor=N,
                 width=footer_width, height=footer_height)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        win.mainloop()

run()
```

What it looks like running:

[image: screenshot of display]

Answer (score 0):

It is because the footer is placed outside the viewing area of the root window.  If you make the root window fullscreen (using `w.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1)` instead of `w.state('zoomed')`, the footer will be shown at the bottom of the root window.  But it works only in fullscreen mode.

You can just using `footer.pack(fill=X)` instead of `footer.place(...)`, like:

```
bg = Canvas(w, bg='#808080', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
bg.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

footer = Canvas(w, bg='#A5A5A5', bd=2, highlightthickness=0, height=30)
footer.pack(fill=X)
```

However this approach does not work if the root window is resized to a small window.

You can use `grid()` to overcome it:

```
w.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # allow header expand vertically
w.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # allow both header and footer expand horizontally

bg = Canvas(w, bg='#808080', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
bg.grid(sticky='nsew')

footer = Canvas(w, bg='#A5A5A5', bd=2, highlightthickness=0, height=30)
footer.grid(sticky='ew')
```